# Using .htaccess to prevent a DDOS attack not working with Permalinks

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, permalinks, ddos

We have become the victim of a vicious DDOS attack on a WordPress site.

Thankfully, they should be easily removed as they are GET requests with the string ?ptrxcz appended to the end of the URL.

With this in mind we have set up rules to give 403 permission error pages to requests that fulfill this using .htacess. The trouble is these don't appear to work with permalinks installed also.

Here is my full .htaccess file as it is.

> ```
> RewriteEngine On
> RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .*ptrxcz.*
> RewriteRule (.*) - [F]
>
> # BEGIN WordPress
>
> <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
> RewriteEngine On
> RewriteBase /
> RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
> RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
> </IfModule>
>
> # END WordPress
> ```

The beginning part is redirecting users with ptrxcz to the 403 page. This works perfectly if I remove the WordPress rules underneath it, but with them included it just never works.

Frustratingly using a negative regex with the QUERY_STRING search works in reverse correctly (blocking everything except request with the query string, as so:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !.*ptrxcz.*
```

(Note the added !)

Does anyone have any idea:

1. Why it doesnt work with permalinks
2. How I can make it work with permalinks
3. Why a negative regex on the query string works but not a positive one.

Comment: Peter, please Answer you own Question, so it doesn't hangs on the "Unanswered" list... Do you know [***5G Blacklist***](http://perishablepress.com/5g-blacklist-2013/)?

Comment: Yeah sorry mate. It said I couldn't answer my own question for 8 hours...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you replace `QUERY_STRING` in the code above with `THE_REQUEST` then this works fine and does exactly as required within WordPress.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but it was severe enough that I brought up a small web server to act as a front end and filter out these requests.  The relevant iptables rule is:

iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -m string --to 70 --algo bm --string 'ptrxcz_' -j DROP

It instructs the system to examine up to the first 70 characters of the request and if it finds 'ptrxcz_ ', to silently drop the request.  I tried returning an error message, but the bandwidth consumed by the error code was not worth it considering there would never be a user on the other end of the connection to read the error.

I created a blog post describing the steps I took:

http://web.htcomp.net/?pageid=85&blogid=2

Larry

Comment: Thanks for the input Larry... Thankfully mine was not so bad that I could block it with simple .htaccess rules but if it comes back stronger then thanks for the heads up!